# Bash : Remove deleted command entry for ranger

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I installed ranger form ubuntu repo and later removed it. Then, installed it form git hub
and built it.
  Now ranger executable is in  `/usr/local/bin/ranger` but when I run ranger
the error `/usr/bin/ranger: No such file or directory` comes.  
 I read that it is because the older 
paths are hashed by bash. I ran the command `hash -r` to remove all the entries.
But still the same error pops up.
 Here's the output of `echo $PATH`:
`/home/my_name/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`
How can I remove older path entry for ranger command?
Edit: type -a ranger outputs:

ranger is a function

```
    ranger () 
{ 
    if [ -z "$RANGER_LEVEL" ]; then
        /usr/bin/ranger "$@";
    else
        exit;
    fi
}
```

ranger is /usr/local/bin/ranger

Comment: What does `type ranger` output?

Comment: Or `type -a ranger`

Comment: The $PATH is often set in .bashrc in your home dir

Comment: updated the output of type -a ranger as question edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got hint from comments under the question. It works here by changing the path in range() function in .bashrc file to /usr/local/bin/ranger.
[This script](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ranger#Preventing_nested_ranger_instances) I had added from arch wiki page on ranger, to avoid nested ranger instances.